# How to increase the number of upsell products in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I created a store in magento. I want to increase the number of upsell products in the product description page.Currently it is showing 4 products in front and other products after clicking next link.
I want to change it to 5.

Answer (score 11):

The upsell block is invoked in the layout by some layout update XML in `catalog.xml`, and the limit is being imposed on/evaluated by this `catalog/product_list_upsell` (aka `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` block instance.

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <!-- snip -->
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- snip -->
        <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
        </block>
        <!-- snip -->
    </reference>
    <!-- snip -->
</catalog_product_view>
```

You can use the above information and your layout's `local.xml` (create it if you don't already have it) to overwrite the `item_limit` value:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.upsell">
        <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>5</limit></action>
        <!--
        if you want them all rendered on one line, change the column_count as well:
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>
        -->
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

More more information, [see the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell class definition](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php).

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Had to update the number in the admin area.  All XML changes were ignored.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I though this might be useful to someone coming here using newer versions of magento (EE) at least.

You can make an update script, this works in Enterprise Edition (1.14) at least:

```
$scope = '0';
$installer->setConfigData('catalog/enterprise_targetrule/upsell_position_limit', '5', 'default', $scope);
```